# Update-Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to insert data in phpmyadmin 
there are two table One is ADD_item and other is Prec 
in **Add_item** table it contain "item_id (**Primary Key**), item_Name, item_shape"
and in Prec table contain Prec_id as a Primary_key and Item_id as a foreign key and other 
But when i want to insert data in to **Prec Table** it's show error

```
 Update-Error: INSERT INTO prec_item(item_id, precured_quantity, total_price, unit_price, retail_price, aapis_price, `precured_date`, `vendor_name`) VALUES (1, 12,12,12,12.12,'2017-06-21','q') Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Kindly tell me how to solve this problem i want to know how to add data on foreign key

Comment: you put dot in between values $market_price.$aapis_pri‌​ce  instead of comma here  $market_price,$aapis_pri‌​ce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO prec_item
(item_id, precured_quantity, total_price, unit_price, retail_price, aapis_price, `precured_date`, `vendor_name`) 
VALUES (1, 12,12,12,12,12,'2017-06-21','q')
```

Try above query.

Hope this will help

Comment: I'm getting data from php form is it work fine there?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO prec_item(item_id, precured_quantity, total_price, unit_price, retail_price, aapis_price, `precured_date`, `vendor_name`) VALUES ($item_name, $quantity,$actual_price,$unit_price,$market_price.$aapis_price,'$child_date','$distributor_name')";

         
        if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
          header('Location: index.php?status=success');
        }else {
          echo "Update-Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

Comment: dear this is my php code please check where problem is... Thanks in advanced

Comment: At this line `,$market_price,$aapis_pri‌​ce` make `.` to `,`

Comment: Thanks @Sagar Gangwal
would you please tell me i want to save two record data on One id how can its possible

Comment: @AwaisButt Is `ItemId` is primary key?

Comment: yes Itemid is primary key in add_item table and foreign key in prec table

Comment: So how can it possible with same `ItemId` multiple entries are there?.You need to remove primary key from there .
One more thing in this query `INSERT INTO prec_item(item_id, precured_quantity, total_price, unit_price, retail_price, aapis_price, precured_date,vendor_name) VALUES ($item_name, ..` you are putting `$item_name` in `item_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the error twice means you will get understand the problem

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

what it mean you column count does not match with your value count ,

**1st** : you put dot  between values `$market_price.$aapis_pri‌​ce`  instead of `comma (,)` here  `$market_price,$aapis_pri‌​ce`

**2nd** : Try to use prepared statement or PDO to avoid sql injection

Comment: Thi thanks actually my level is beginner so sometime i can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

brother you should try this code instead of your code hope it will help you.

```
require_once('dbconnect.php');
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO prec_item(item_id, precured_quantity, total_price, unit_price, retail_price, aapis_price, precured_date, vendor_name) VALUES('".$item_name."', '".$quantity."','".$actual_price."','".$unit_price."','".$market_price."','".$aapis_pri‌​ce."','".$child_date."','".$d‌​istributor_name."')");
mysqli_close($con); 

 if ($conn->query($insert) == TRUE) 
 { 
header('Location: index.php?status=success'); 
}
else 
{
    echo "Update-Error: " . $insert . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
    }
```

In `dbconnect.php`

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'username';
$dbPassword = 'password';
$dbName = 'dbname';

//Connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

//Display error if failed to connect
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
    exit();
}
?>
```